# Plotting in RGB system

Tags: r, rgb

I have the following matrix:

```
[1,] 0.41037159 0.035512698 0.29994815
[2,] 0.78614949 0.011315428 0.62326616
[3,] 0.42033801 0.061607952 0.25401746
[4,] 0.09617148 0.018400841 0.03194410
[5,] 0.20674738 0.006731245 0.04494770
[6,] 0.04557131 0.004572941 0.21202555
[7,] 0.34248003 0.049949400 0.15443408
[8,] 0.02531455 0.000000000 0.42509625
[9,] 0.90997863 0.997772243 0.22139140
[10,] 0.76310619 0.509855546 0.03353221
[11,] 0.00000000 0.012677219 0.46590562
[12,] 0.25175140 0.053030978 0.20539943
[13,] 0.45103356 0.066157072 0.25589777
[14,] 0.05925331 0.019370010 0.00000000
[15,] 0.47797323 0.028505669 0.50553749
[16,] 0.19155010 0.104653515 0.11193315
[17,] 0.51185644 0.135238576 0.10319339
[18,] 0.39407653 0.052845711 0.91779848
[19,] 0.13960324 0.004667373 0.06151135
[20,] 0.41404594 0.183680484 0.01052881
[21,] 0.16835070 0.045960588 0.99267994
[22,] 0.48752986 0.069917560 0.36119324
[23,] 0.37388790 0.030336825 0.21154492
[24,] 0.24967125 0.002199422 0.19477217
```

These values are coming from the values of the first three pca axes.

I also have the x, y coordinates of the 24 values:

```
        x        y
ABO  6.722778 46.27972
ANG -2.889466 56.64358
AUB  2.848056 44.68500
BPN -2.980000 48.07000
BRU  8.658332 47.02055
CHA  4.275278 46.43444
GAS  1.638333 43.15556
GNS -2.533333 49.45000
HFD -2.708111 52.06120
HOL 10.133333 54.33333
JER -2.116667 49.20000
LMS  1.332222 45.77083
MAN -0.702778 47.82861
MAR -1.083611 46.42222
MON  5.875556 47.19194
NOR -0.325278 49.20444
NRC 11.056110 60.79917
OUL -6.016670 33.41667
PMT  7.666667 45.06667
PRP -4.096389 47.99667
RMG 15.661940 38.11139
SAL  2.495000 45.13889
TAR  5.953056 45.53611
VOS  7.385556 48.00917
```

I want to plot the values of the pca using their coordinates into an RGB system.

I tried :

```
rgb(pca_matrix)
```

It indeed gives me the values of RGB system but I can't figure it out correctly how I should plot them using these coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you need to plot points in different colors, first, save your `rgb()` output as object.

```
coll<-rgb(pca_matrix)
```

Then use, for example, function `plot()` to plot points and set colors according to saved object `coll`. Your second data frame was named as `df` in example.

```
plot(df$x,df$y,col=coll,pch=16,cex=2)
```

[image]